# Read Excel data from C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to read data from an Excel sheet using Office.Interoperability.Excel namespace. I'd like to get the first row of the sheet as the first row contains the headers, without specifying the start and end cells. Because I wouldn't know if a new column is added to the sheet.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelObj = new Application();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myBook = excelObj.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\myFile.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 0, 0);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet mySheet = (Worksheet)myBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

    Range range = mySheet.Cells.EntireRow;
```

Here, the range becomes the entire range and it doesn't get limited to the number of header columns. Also I've a huge data of about 10,000 rows to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
Range headers = mySheet.UsedRange.Rows(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you requirement doesnt involve writing back to the excel file I would suggest that you use Excel Data Reader (http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) its a lot easier to use, doesnt require excel on the server and its faster

Comment: +1. Yes! All this Interop ceremonial... yawn. And if you want to write as well: Flexcel or Gembox (not free though).

Comment: gr8 tool... but i wanted exporting back to excel as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I just answered another Excel reading question here: [C# converting .xls to .csv without Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573529/c-converting-xls-to-csv-without-excel/7573695#7573695)

The [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library is perfect for your task. I use it myself for those numbers of rows and above.

I don't know what you are doing with the rows once they are read from Excel, but if you a looking at some processing that could be broken down into step, have a look at [Rhino.Etl](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-etl) for that. It's a really powerful way to process large amounts of data.