# How to export a .xls file from a website as a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, export-to-csv

I am trying to export self updating .xls file from other website to mine as csv, so that I will be able to create "Live data graphs" using Highcharts JS for different parameters from this , which also update automatically according to the file.

OR

I have another method, same self updating data is on a website in form of table which gets updated with time. So , is it possilble to pull data from there for specific parameters and generate live data graphs?

Please Help.....

Comment: Just ask the people who generate the XLS to provide it as CSV to you.  Should be trivial for them and they may be interested in what you are doing with the data.

Comment: Better option would be a database. Many types available and would serve you better than having tons of Excel files...then tons of CSV files.

Comment: So is it possible that database get synchronize with the data on the website...@wergeld

Comment: If it is your website then I would assume you could add a DB backend. If it is not your website then you are at the whim of the devs who run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a Google spreadsheet?

http://dataist.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/using-google-spreadsheet-as-a-database/

Comment: Because the data keep on adding to the excel files with every minute for a month and then the website create a new file for the another month... @jlbriggs

Comment: My files are too long for the google spreadsheet.. :'( @jlbiggs

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want to convert an `.xls` file to `.csv` ?
Then you'll want to look at this article:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yuanwang200409/how-to-convert-xls-file-into-csv-file-in-c-sharp/

As well as consider some answers on SO:

- [Is there any simple way to convert .xls file to .csv file? (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536181/is-there-any-simple-way-to-convert-xls-file-to-csv-file-excel)
- [C# converting .xls to .csv without Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573529/c-sharp-converting-xls-to-csv-without-excel)

Personally I like the solution to extract `.xls` into dataset and then generate you `.csv` from datatble. (see [c# datatable to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but this is in C#, I want this is for my website, so I would it need any scripting for that... I don't know I am right or not @artur udod

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice it's not actually c# =))